# Developing a web application in python with neo4j

Tags: python, django, neo4j, recommendation-engine

I'm planning to implement a recommendation engine, of which details are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554873/neural-network-based-ranking-of-documents).
'Python' is my preferred choice along with 'neo4j' Database. Can anyone please point out, how integration of 'neo4j' with any web framework like 'django' can be done?. Is it possible to integrate them just like 'PHP'integrates with 'MySQL'? .

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I dont see why not. You can integrate this with Django & serve requests through it...

1. [Modeling Categories in Graph Database](http://blog.neo4j.org/2010/03/modeling-categories-in-graph-database.html)
2. [Neo4J shop categories example](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/python-shop-categories)
3. [Neo4j and django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866635/neo4j-and-django-models)
4. [Django & Neo4j - domain modeling that kicks ass.](http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/django-and-neo4j-domain-modeling-that-kicks-ass)
5. [Seamless Django & Neo4j integration](http://journal.thobe.org/2009/12/seamless-neo4j-integration-in-django.html)

Hope this helps... I myself was able to integrate almost entire [IMDB](http://imdb.com) into Neo4j & serve it up through Django.

Answer (score 5):

Check this neo4j python library https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client out. It uses rest api of neo4j. If you are not planning to use the REST API, you may consider Jython implementation which will directly connect to the database. I heard that some hackers implementing neo4j backend for django. But I think it is not mature enough to develop web site.

Answer (score 4):

You may still need some sql database like sqlite if you plan to use some Django Features like authentication. But, if you just want to build your recommendation engine, you can use Django with **no-database**. And, you build your backend in python using neo4j without worrying first about Django which could integrates with it a priori seamlessly.

Links for neo4j and python:

[Installation] http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/python-embedded.html

[Usage] http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-python-embedded.html

Comment: as of March 2013, these links are dead :/

Answer (score 4):

We've updated the old Django integration to use [neo4j-rest-client](http://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client)- it's called [neo4django](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/). We've made some major improvements over the old integration, and are using it successfully to build [Scholrly](http://scholr.ly). It's not quite in production, but it's something.

The library allows model definition, query sets with automated indexing, and works alongside a relational database- so you can still use contrib modules based on the standard ORM.

I've posted a bit about it [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739398/which-neo4j-to-use-with-django/7761472#7761472) on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866635/neo4j-and-django-models/7761360#7761360) if you're interested!

Comment: If i choose neo4j-embedded, would I be able to run it inside django?. I'm a beginner, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Definitely, but only on the same machine as the graph database. It also won't have any sort of ORM-style support- you'll be creating nodes/relationships and managing transactions yourself.